# Spring Security only authenticating GET Request. POST ,PUT or DELETE Request showing 401 error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to set Role-based access control. I have 3 Roles. EMPLOYEE, MANAGER, ADMIN.
EMPLOYEE can view employee list or a single employee.
MANAGER can view, update or add employee.
ADMIN can view, update,add or delete.

In my case, Employee can send GET request and it works fine. But when I am trying to send POST request it should get a 403 error. But it is getting 401.
Even MANAGER and ADMIN are also getting the same 401 error.

I am using basic authentication. `httpBasic()` and `csrf()` method has been deprecated. so I used `csrf(Customizer.withDefaults())` and `httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())`.
What is the problem?

I am using Spring Boot : 3.1.0
spring-security-web: 6.1.0

```
@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager(){
    UserDetails Jerin  = User.builder()
            .username("user1")
            .password("{noop}1234")
            .roles("EMPLOYEE")
            .build();

    UserDetails Recy  = User.builder()
            .username("user2")
            .password("{noop}1234")
            .roles("EMPLOYEE", "MANAGER")
            .build();

    UserDetails Usha  = User.builder()
            .username("user3")
            .password("{noop}1234")
            .roles("EMPLOYEE","MANAGER","ADMIN")
            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(Jerin,Recy,Usha);

}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

    //Restriction based on ROLE
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(configure ->
            configure
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET , "/api/employees").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET , "/api/employees/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST , "/api/employees").hasRole("MANAGER")
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT , "/api/employees").hasRole("MANAGER")
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE , "/api/employees/**").hasRole("ADMIN")

    );

    http
        .csrf(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: What are the names of the roles in the database? You enabled CSRF tokens make sure you are sending them with your requests.

Comment: Roles are InMemoryUserDetailsManager. without ROLE_ prefix. Just "EMPLOYEE", "MANAGER" and "ADMIN". And I wanted to disable csrf(), but I could not find any way to disable it.

Comment: If they don't have `ROLE_` prefix use `hasAuthority` instead of `hasROle`. Use `Customizer.disabled()` to disable csrf.

Comment: In my case, Customizer only has withDefaults() method. disabled() method not found.

Comment: Sorry my bad you need `csrf( (csrf) -> csrf.disable())`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Disabling csrf solved my problem.